# WinForm application restarting itself after Close

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

We have a WinForm application that restarts even after closing but then closes again. The problem that we are facing is as follows:
 - The user double-clicks the exe to launch the application.
 - Before the application launches completely, the user closes the session by clicking on the close-button.
 - The application closes but then re-flashes once more on the screen and shuts down.
 Even though the application windows is closed, the background process remains. From the dumps that we saw, the main forms "IsDisposed" property is set to true. The code in our application looks like this:

```
public Form MainForm {
    get {
        if (frmApp == null || frmApp.isDisposed) {
            _mainForm = new frmApp();
        }
    }
}
```

So, at all the places we use this MainForm property to access our main winForm.
What happens is whenever every time "MainForm" is encountered in the code, due to isDisposed being set to true, it tries to create the form again. This goes on recursively whenever "MainForm" is encountered.
However, my concern, is why does it even re-flash after closing the form once, eventually leading to the above mentioned behavior.

Here is the stack trace from WinDBG:

```
 000000c01bdfbb40 00007fff6b3e53b3 System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
 000000c01bdfbbe0 00007fff6ba56f59 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int32, Int64, Int64)
 000000c01bdfbfb8 00007fff903321fe [InlinedCallFrame: 000000c01bdfbfb8] System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32)
 000000c01bdfbfb8 00007fff6b469064 [InlinedCallFrame: 000000c01bdfbfb8] System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32)
 000000c01bdfbf90 00007fff6b469064 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32)
 000000c01bdfc040 00007fff6b3e250c System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean)
 000000c01bdfc0f0 00007fff6b3f0cde System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean)
 000000c01bdfc150 00007fff6b43dd56 System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()
```

Starting from below in the call stack, After "Show->SetVisibleCore->SetVisibleCore" is invoked, it executes few native window methods and then invokes "CallBack" which is followed by the call stack to launch the window again. Sorry, I can't post the whole call stack here because of privacy issues. However, any leads or any suggestions as to what can we do to identify the root cause of the issue would be appreciated. Its causing our citrix box from which the application is launched to crash because the user object count is hitting the specified limit leading to an angry client.

This is the stack trace from VS:

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(bool value)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(bool value)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()    Unknown
```

I was going through the comments provided for the DebuggableCallback method here:[NativeWindows](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeWindow.cs) and it says that it is called when a windows message is sent to this window. Is it possible due to few of the events that are pending execution may be causing this when they are executed later?

Comment: Coming from a background of privicy issues, is there something you can do to make a minimal viable example (using delays etc) to fabricate something so we can replicate the behavior? My guess is something in the initial project where the mainform is generated is kicking in.

Comment: I am really not sure if I would be able to re-create this with a sample application. However, I'll give it a try. But again it might be an issue with our common platform framework and may not be happening in the actual windows code.

Comment: It's impossible to answer without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. That said, based on your own analysis, it's not clear to me why you aren't just looking into places where you retrieve the `MainForm` property during exit, thus causing the new window to be created? Or even more to the point, why do you think it's even correct to recreate the window if the old one had been disposed. Is there a normal user scenario where that even makes sense? ...

Comment: ... And if the answer to that is "yes", then why not just create a flag that indicates the program is exiting, and suppress the "create new window" logic if that flag is set?

Comment: This is legacy code. So, we had the same doubt as to why are we checking for "IsDisposed" and based on that deciding whether to create the form instance or not. So, I removed "IsDisposed" and tried the scenario again thinking that might avoid the problem, although not necessarily resolve the actual issue causing it to re-launch. However, it did not work. What you mentioned is correct. It doesn't make sense there. I understand the fact it would be very difficult to provide any answer without more information. But yes, any directions to identify the problem might help....

Comment: or may be any post regarding similar problem observed by anyone else (may not be exactly same), would definitely help us in debugging this issue.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce it so far using a sample application.